# Having trouble copying adjacent cells when FindNext match is found

Tags: excel, vba

In Column A of Sheet 1, I have a list of serial numbers which contain duplicates. I want to delete all duplicates and instead come up with a history column which captures all the information of the adjacent cells with regards to that serial number. The logic of my script goes like this: 1) Filter all distinct serial numbers into a new sheet 2) For each cell in new sheet, find all matching cells in sheet 1 3) If they match then copy adjacent columns information and create an new column with new matching information 4) The more serial duplicates are, the bigger the "history" cell of that serial number is going to have

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RSbo.jpg

When I use "FindPN.Interior.ColorIndex = 3", the program does fine, finding all the 1's in the column and coloring them red. I just want to copy each the 3 cells' values that are adjacent to each '1' in Column A. I have used a Dictionary to create a dynamic variable to spit out the final cell that I want, but when I run the program, I am having problems understanding how the place the variables in the FindNext loop to spit out each different B2, C2, and D2.

```
Sub FindPN1() 'simplified script finding all the 1's in Sheet 1

Dim I, J, K, L, Atotal As Integer
Dim FindPN, FoundPN As Range
Dim UniqueValue As Range
Dim strStatus, strDate, strComments As Object

Atotal = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets(1)
For I = 2 To Atotal

    Set FindPN = Sheets(1).Columns(1).Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not FindPN Is Nothing Then
            Set FoundPN = FindPN

            Set strStatus = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For J = 1 To Atotal
                strStatus(J) = Range("B" & I).Value
            Next

            Set strComments = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For K = 1 To Atotal
                strComments(K) = Range("C" & I).Value
            Next

            Set strDate = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For L = 1 To Atotal
                strDate(L) = Range("D" & I).Value
            Next

            Range("A15").Value = strDate(1)
            'FindPN.Interior.ColorIndex = 3


            Do
                Set FindPN = .Columns(1).FindNext(After:=FindPN)

                If Not FindPN Is Nothing Then
                    strStatus(J) = Range("B" & I).Value
                    strComments(K) = Range("C" & I).Value
                    strDate(L) = Range("D" & I).Value

                    'FindPN.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                    Range("B15").Value = strDate(3)

                    If FindPN.Address = FoundPN.Address Then Exit Do
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End With
```

The problem I am having is not knowing how to store my variables and having them spit out the 'History' Cell the way that I want. I have been practicing by going inside the loop to see where each variable gets defined but it seems like the strDate is always spitting out the date corresponding to the first 1.

Comment: "Holly shambles, Batman"  there is _so_ much wrong here.  Mixture of qualified and unqualified worksheet/range references. `Dim` without specific type (results in Variants).  Use of Integer (should be Long).  Reliance on sheet position (`Sheets(1)`).  Late binding to Dictionary object.  `Find` uses last used values for a number of parameters unless you specify them (may give unexpected results).  Lack of sample data set and corresponding expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this much simpler - use a single dictionary and loop over the rows.

Add new Id's (and their "history" value) where they don't exist: if an id is already in the dictionary then append the new piece of history to the existing value.

When done, loop over the dictionary and write out the keys and the values.

```
Sub CombineRows()

    Dim i As Long, h, k, lastRow As Long
    Dim dict As Object, wsSrc As Worksheet

    Set wsSrc = Sheets(1)
    lastRow = wsSrc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        With Sheets(1).Rows(i)
            k = .Cells(1).Value
            h = .Cells(2).Value & "|" & _
                .Cells(4).Text & "|" & _
                .Cells(3).Value
            If dict.exists(k) Then
                dict(k) = dict(k) & vbLf & h
            Else
                dict.Add k, h
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    DumpDict dict, Sheets(2).Range("A1")

End Sub

'write out dictionary content starting at "rng"
Sub DumpDict(dict As Object, rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, k
    Set c = rng.Cells(1)
    For Each k In dict.keys
        c.Value = k
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = dict(k)
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Time thanks for your help! I'm actually having another problem. I know that the dictionary dumps into 2 columns (A and B) on the second sheet. I want to keep the history column, but move it to Column C. I did that by changing `c.Offset(0,2).value = dict(k)` . But when I do an If statement regarding the new Column A, the data won't autofill into Column B. I think the dictionary has something to do with it. Im taliking about `If Range("A" & i).Value = 1 Then Range("A" & i).Offset(0,1).Value = "some string" ` but Column B does not fill.

Comment: Sorry I can't follow what you're trying to do.  Maybe describe in words what outcome you want.

Comment: It's ok Tim I figured it out. The problem was I set the wrong range for the For Loop. I do have one other question though. Say I want to check the text of the very first Key of the dictionary. https://imgur.com/a/VuJ2CmC I want to see the first key of each cell and depending on "repaired" "needs repair" or "retired" the next column to the right will have a specific phrase. I know I need to loop through the dictionary but I am a little confused.

Comment: The value associated with each key is a vbLf-delimited list of values, so if you need to you can use `arr = Split(dict(k), vbLf)` and `arr` will be a zero-based array with one "line" per element.  Check `arr(0)` for your string of interest.